# substitutes for enable_if to enable a method for only one template value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, templates, sfinae

I would like to make a template class limit an overloaded method like this example:

```
template<int N>
class foo {
  public:
    void add(int a, int* b) {*b = a + N;} 
    int add(std::enable_if<N == 0, int> a, int b) {return a + b}
}
```

(Example changed to reflect complications not present in the original example.)

However, I am using Visual Studio, whose support for SFINAE (and thus enable_if) is still not very good.  (I'm not sure if it would work in that simple example; in my actual situation I'm using `std::enable_if` on a class reference and using a member of that class, and it doesn't work.)  The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579182/msvc-2013-type-is-not-a-member-of-stdenable-iffalse-void) (which has essentially the same error message I got) suggested using tag dispatching as an alternative, but I'm not sure how that would work if I want the function to simply be unavailable at all with those argument types, or if I want to overload a constructor in this manner.

Comment: Should be `int add(std::enable_if<N == 0, int>::type a, int b)` in C++11, or `int add(std::enable_if_t<N == 0, int> a, int b)` in C++14

Comment: Thank you; I'll have to try that out.  If I was simply misusing enable_if and fixing it solves that, that would be a convenient solution.

Comment: The problem isn’t Visual Studio; it’s that this isn’t valid. The parameter to `enable_if` must depend on a template parameter *of the function*, not *of the class*. Here, by the time you try to instantiate `add`, the compiler already knows what `N` is, so the `enable_if` is invalid.

Comment: Daniel H: Thank you.  I'd been misunderstanding what the problem was; looking with the information you provided led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842478/select-class-constructor-using-enable-if.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be made into a function template. And the condition in the `enable_if` needs to be made dependent on a template parameter of the function template so that it is not substituted into early.

```
template<int M = N, 
         class = typename std::enable_if<M == 0>::type>
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

Comment: You might want to make that `template <typename..., int M = N, class = typename std::enable_if<M == 0>::type>`, or you could just call `add<0>` for any instantiation.

Comment: @DanielH Murphy, Machiavelli, etc.

Comment: I had actually not heard that metaphor before. I agree with it to a point, but if I see a template method in a class and I’m not too familiar with SFINAE or template metaprogramming (which is the case for a lot of C++ programmers), I won’t know which template parameters it’s safe to use myself and which it’s not. In this case it’s simple, but where I first saw the trick of putting the extra `typename...` pack, there were some template parameters which were actually parameters for the caller, and it was useful to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I see `std::enable_if` used with return type

```
template<int N>
class foo {
  public:
    int add(int a) 
     {return a + N;} 

    template <int M = N>
    typename std::enable_if<M == 0, int>::type add(int a, int b)
     {return a + b}
}
```

This didn't work?

Another way can be the use of a base class (`bar`, in the following example) that define only `add(int, int)` and only in the required specialization.

```
template <int N>
struct bar
 { int add (int a, int b) = delete; };

template <>
struct bar<0>
 { int add (int a, int b) { return a + b; } };

template <int N>
struct foo : public bar<N>
 { using bar<N>::add; void add (int a, int * b) { *b = a + N; } };

int main()
 {
   foo<0>  f0;
   foo<1>  f1;

   int b { 0 };

   f0.add(1, &b);
   f0.add(1, 2);

   f1.add(1, &b);
   //f1.add(1, 2); // compilation error
 }
```

Observe that the `using bar<N>::add` in `foo` is required because, otherwise, the `add(int)` in `foo` hide the `add(int, int)` in `bar`.

And that this `using` impose the `int add (int a, int b) = delete;` in the generic version of `bar<N>`.

If the name of the two function is different, say `add2()` for the version with 2 integer arguments, the example become simply as follows

```
template <int N>
struct bar
 { };

template <>
struct bar<0>
 { int add2 (int a, int b) { return a + b; } };

template <int N>
struct foo : public bar<N>
 { void add (int a, int * b) { *b = a + N; } };

int main()
 {
   foo<0>  f0;
   foo<1>  f1;

   int b { 0 };

   f0.add(1, &b);
   f0.add2(1, 2);

   f1.add(1, &b);
   //f1.add2(1, 2); // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Return type is normal, but as mentioned I'm using it in a constructor, where there is no return type.  The other idea might work; is there a reason it requires a base class rather than just defining it with those arguments directly as delete, and then specializing?

Comment: @YitzhakKornbluth - yes: with a constructor you can't enable/disable the return value; see also the T.C. answer: should work with constructors too. The reason for a base class is that in a base class you can differentiate the only function that is different in the two cases (the `add()` returning `int`); if you specialize the entire `foo` class/struct (I suppose a more complicated class/struct) you have to replicate all common code in both specializations.

Comment: @YitzhakKornbluth - answer modified to reflect your modified example (and corrected an error in the return type enable/disable example).

Answer (score 0):

No simple transformation of your code is legal.  The signature of methods to template classes must be legal.

```
template<class D, bool> // false case
struct add_base {
  void add(int* a, int b) {*a += b}      
  D*self(){return static_cast<D*>(this);}
  D const*self()const{return static_cast<D const*>(this);}
};
template<class D>
struct add_base<D,true>:add_base<D,false> {
  using base=add_base<D,false>;
  using base::self;
  using base::add; // for overload resolution
  int add(int a, int b) {return a + b}
};

template<int N>
class foo: add_base<foo<N>, N==0> {
  using base = add_base<foo<N>, N==0>;
  template<class D, bool b>
  friend class add_base<D, b>;// may be a syntax error here.
public:
  using base::add;
};
```

here I assume the real `add` wants to use `this`; in this case use `self()` in its implementation.

There are other techniques using template parameters with default values, but their legality under a strict reading of the standard is questionable.  The problem is the standard mandates all template functions have a valid specialization, and mostnuse of those techniques breaks that rule.  There are different readings of the standard under which they may be legal.

You could also wait for [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a) concepts.

Comment: Thank you, but the example with 1 vs 2 ints was just for simplicity; the actual case has entirely different classes in the arguments.  I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: @max fixed, and yes.